# Creating a stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart using ggplot but unable to add multiple stacks to my bar. Im trying to get each stack to show the breakdown of primary, secondary and post16 (represented by different colours), whilst the overall hight represents the total. As you can see below the bars aren't quite correct as i am missing the coours to represent the breakdown, I'm pretty sure this will comes from the geom_col() argument but unsure of the fix.

```
data:
df <- read_table("region    total    primary   secondary    post16
            East      21       4         8            9
            Mid       28       3         15           10
            North     7        2         4            1
            South     13       3         5            5")


code:
 ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(region), y = total, fill = "total")) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_col(aes(y = primary, fill = "prim")) +
  geom_col(aes(y = secondary, fill = "seco")) +
  geom_col(aes(y = post16, fill = "p16")) +
  coord_flip()
```

Current plot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a re-write here. The key is transforming the data [into long form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65923405/10276092):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("region    total    primary   secondary    post16
                East      21       4         8            9
                Mid       28       3         15           10
                North     7        2         4            1
                South     13       3         5            5")

df %>% 
  dplyr::select(-total) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-region) %>% 
  mutate(name = fct_relevel(name, "primary", "secondary", "post16")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = region, y = value, fill = name)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok perfect, for some reason i'm getting an error when i try to deselect columns 'Error in select(., -total) : unused argument (-total)', any idea why this is

Comment: @Joe There are multiple libraries with `select()` functions (i.e. MASS), we can call the tidyverse/dplyr one explicitly `dplyr::select()`.

Comment: ah yep good spot

Comment: sorry one last thing, is there any way the column order can be changed on the plot so we have green, blue, red (primary, secondary, post16)?

Comment: We can use `fct_relevel()` to reorder factors. And/Or use `scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "blue", "red"))` to change the colors. (I've picked terrible named colors, you can use #HEX or any of the other named colors https://r-charts.com/colors/

Comment: Right ok, not quite sure the arguments needed for ```fct_relevel()``` as in my data they are already in the order of; primary, secondary, post16. It just then changes on the plot?